# Cannot add or update a simple row to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable, sql-update

Coming from an Access DB background using SQL select statements, I am finding that there is more work involved in pushing data into an SQL Server database and updating records. My initial understanding of adding records in SQL Server required a VERY LONG statement that included the INSERT command. This to me seems to be unnecessarily complicated and I have to believe that with .NET today, it has to be much simpler.

I have researched and reviewed several code samples for `DataTable`, `DataSet`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlAdapters`, etc. NONE of them work for me despite the fact that my code has no errors in it.  I've gone through so many mutations of these examples that I am appealing to Stack Overflow for some help.

Here's what I am trying to do.

1. Connect to a SQL Server hosted externally (works!)
2. Open a single table called `Dongles`.
3. Check for a row using the serial number as a criteria.
4. If it exists, UPDATE the record.
5. If not, then ADD the new record.

I am providing the latest mutation of the code samples that I have worked with. Before running the code, I manually added 1 record to the database so I know the SerialNumber argument matches.  Unfortunately, the `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` statement returns false and the update is never attempted.

Now I will tell you this....I have tried other mutations that did successfully go through the lines that update each field.  But when the Update() function was called (successfully), nothing was propagated to the actual database.

Here's the code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dongles WHERE SerialNumber = " + m_dongle.SerialNumber, server.SQLConnection);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   dt.Rows[0]["IsLeased"] = m_dongle.IsLeased == true ? 1 : 0;
   dt.Rows[0]["LeaseDaysRemaining"] = m_dongle.LeaseDaysRemaining;
   dt.Rows[0]["DateAssigned"] = DateTime.Now;
   dt.Rows[0]["ConfiguredBy"] = m_dongle.ConfiguredBy;
   dt.Rows[0]["LicenseHolder"] = m_dongle.LicenseHolder;
   dt.Rows[0]["ContactName"] = m_dongle.ContactName;
   dt.Rows[0]["ContactPhone"] = m_dongle.ContactPhone;
   dt.Rows[0]["ContactEmail"] = m_dongle.ContactEmail;
   dt.Rows[0]["SerialNumber"] = m_dongle.SerialNumber;
   dt.Rows[0]["IsNetworkDongle"] = m_dongle.IsNetworkDongle;
   dt.Rows[0]["NetworkMaxUsers"] = m_dongle.NetworkMaxUsers;
   dt.Rows[0]["NetworkAbsoluteMaxUsers"] = m_dongle.NetworkAbsoluteMaxUsers;
   dt.Rows[0]["IsAssigned"] = m_dongle.IsAssigned;
   dt.Rows[0]["DongleModel"] = m_dongle.DongleModel;
   dt.Rows[0]["SalesforceID"] = m_dongle.SalesforceID;

   da.Update(dt);

   MessageBox.Show("Dongle profile updated successfully.", "Profile Saved", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

Comment: if ado.net & DataTable is too complicated for you you could check some ORM's with tools for example Entity Framework, if you love some magic :)

Comment: Hey JD, **to accept answer(s), please click on the check box outline to the left of the answer(s)**. People would appreciate that and will be more willing to help in the future. Like many other people here, I do have solution for you but would not give it just because you are not giving back...sorry

Comment: Try it without the `where` clause as a sanity check.

Answer (score 4):

What kind of column is `SerialNumber`?? If it's a string column, you would need to put quotes around the parameter - and while you're at it, to prevent SQL injection attacks - use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL statements... (as an added benefit, the parameters will automagically use quotes around values, where needed):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dongles WHERE SerialNumber = @SerialNo", server.SQLConnection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = m_dongle.SerialNumber.Trim();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    .......
}
```